# One box object detection

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I am using a faster rcnn model to predict one object in an image. There can only be one object in each image.

Is it possible to force Faster Rcnn to train and predict as if it should only find one object per image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all depends only on data that you train on.

But I don't think that fast-rcnn is the best solution for this case: it's "brute force" solution (if only one object)- but if the data is really complex and such big object detection model worth it, try to use modern convolution-based object detection architectures like YOLO or SSD